# MySQL Create list of related courses

Tags: mysql, join, relationships

I'm updating a website for our school, and we have a list of courses available.

The list of courses is in tbl_course_details:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_course_details` (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `course_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `course_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `course_details` longtext NOT NULL,
    `course_added_by` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `course_last_updated` int(30) NOT NULL,
    `course_menu_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
```

I also have a table called tbl_course_related:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_course_related` (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `course_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `related_course_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`),
    KEY `course_id` (`course_id`),
    KEY `related_course_id` (`related_course_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=25;
```

When a staff member edits a course, they also get a list of all courses (Except the course they are currently editing). It also has check boxes next to them, so that if a course is related to the course they are editing, they tick the box.

My course details table has 3 courses in it at the moment:

```
Unique ID    Course Name
---------------------------
1            Geography
2            History
3            Art
```

As an example, i've made geography related to history, and history related to art, so my relationship table looks like:

```
Unique ID    Course ID     Related Course Id
--------------------------------------------
1            1             2
2            2             1
3            2             3
4            3             2
```

I hope this makes sense so far. 
Now, If a staff member went to edit the Geography Course (course ID: 1), then I would like a list of courses to contain History and Art, and only the history checkbox is ticked.

My current SQL query looks like this (although I have changed it around a bit and nothings worked so far):

```
SELECT d.uid, 
       d.course_name,
       r.related_course_id
FROM tbl_course_details d
LEFT JOIN tbl_course_related r
    ON r.course_id = d.uid 
AND d.uid!=:courseId
```

However this makes the list look like this (if I edit geography)

```
Related?   Course Name
No         History
Yes        History
No         Art
```

Obviously I dont want history in the list twice, especially with conflicting information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ea43/4). If in result dataset `r.related_course_id` is not NULL then you should tick a checkbox

```
SELECT d.uid, 
       d.course_name,
       r.related_course_id
FROM tbl_course_details d
LEFT JOIN tbl_course_related r
    ON (r.course_id = d.uid) and (r.Related_Course_Id=:courseId)

where d.uid!=:courseId
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work great at the moment, I'll try testing it on a larger dataset, but it looks like its exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

TRy this ::

```
SELECT d.uid, 
       d.course_name,
       r.related_course_id
FROM tbl_course_details d
LEFT JOIN tbl_course_related r
    ON r.course_id = d.uid 
AND d.uid!=:courseId

GROUP BY r.course_id
```

OR You can use DISTINCT::

```
SELECT 
       DISTINCT(d.course_name),
d.uid,            
r.related_course_id
    FROM tbl_course_details d
    LEFT JOIN tbl_course_related r
        ON r.course_id = d.uid 
    AND d.uid!=:courseId


GROUP BY r.course_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried a group by clause and it didn't work as expected, although it removed the duplicate course from the list, the course instance removed was also the one linking it with the current course being edited